# I want to make cluster of sentences but now i don't know that how many cluster will be made

Tags: cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, doc2vec, sentence, nlp-question-answering

I have calculated the embedding with the help of doc2vec and I have also calculated the distance between sentences in vector form. now I have a vector of sentences that tells the distance between them(sentences). how can I cluster them without giving the number of clusters? I have used k-means and agglomerative algo but they are not giving me good results. can anybody tell me the best method to determine the optimal number of clusters?

Comment: What evaluation are you using to determine that your existing results are "not good"? Are you sure that the `Doc2Vec` step is running well? (Have you been able to rigorously evaluate its results, separately from the attempted-clustering? Without eeeing your code, & just hearing the results are unsaisfactory, any number of improvable unshown things you're doing might be going wrong.) What's your ultimate goal with the clustering, and do you have a way to score results which could be used to optimize the choice of parameters for clustering?

Comment: I just want to know how can i decide the number of clusters.

Comment: Try different values & pick the one that scores best on an repeatable evaluation of the fitness of the resulting clusters for your specific goals.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If it doesn't do what you want, I have a few other code samples to share. This may be the best option. The best option to use, can change, based on the dataset that you feed into the algo.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation
import distance
    
words = "kitten belly squooshy merley best eating google feedback face extension impressed map feedback google eating face extension climbing key".split(" ") #Replace this line
words = np.asarray(words) #So that indexing with a list will work
lev_similarity = -1*np.array([[distance.levenshtein(w1,w2) for w1 in words] for w2 in words])

affprop = AffinityPropagation(affinity="precomputed", damping=0.5)
affprop.fit(lev_similarity)
for cluster_id in np.unique(affprop.labels_):
    exemplar = words[affprop.cluster_centers_indices_[cluster_id]]
    cluster = np.unique(words[np.nonzero(affprop.labels_==cluster_id)])
    cluster_str = ", ".join(cluster)
    print(" - *%s:* %s" % (exemplar, cluster_str))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I think you are using the method for making clusters of words but I have to create clusters of sentences.